# FFMPEG RTP Multicast concatenate multiple audio files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I'm running the following command which creates a multicast RTP stream that my devices listen on:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/usr/test.mp3 -filter_complex "aresample=8000,asetnsamples=n=160,volume=-4dB" -acodec pcm_mulaw -ac 1 -vn -f rtp rtp://225.0.0.10:536
```

This plays the test.mp3 track. However, I have a chime.mp3 file that I want to play before the actual main test.mp3 plays. Does anyone know if it's possible to concatenate the two files so they play in a single command and stream?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/usr/chime.mp3 -re -i /home/usr/test.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1]concat=n=2:a=1:v=0,aresample=8000,asetnsamples=n=160,volume=-4dB" -acodec pcm_mulaw -ac 1 -vn -f rtp rtp://225.0.0.10:536
```

Comment: Thank you. I've just tried this but the second file the test.mp3 starts playing and cuts off immediately. So it is attempting to concatenate it but seems to be ending before it finishes for some reason. Any idea why?

Comment: @JohnRoberts Show your command and the full log.